# Why is the condition in this callback always returns false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have a home SPA based on Vue. One of the components is driven by a `v-if="isDisplayed`".

This `isDisplayed` is set by listening to a MQTT topic (see footnote) and new messages received are handled by the following function (I sepcifically used `'hello'` instead of `false` to make sure the switch goes there). The `topic` of interest is `display_school_edt`.

```
mqttMessage(topic, message) {
      console.log(`App.vue received topic ${topic} with payload '${message}'`)
      if (topic === "dash/reload") {
        window.location.href = window.location.href
        document.location.reload(true);
      }
      if (topic === "dash/darkmode") {
        this.nightmode = JSON.parse(message) ? "night" : "day";
      }
      // this is the part I have problems with, I left everything for completness
      if (topic === "display_school_edt") {
        console.log(`edt display received: '${message}'`);
        if (message === 'on') {
          this.isEdtDisplayed = true
        } else {
          this.isEdtDisplayed = 'hello'
        }
        // I initially went for the ternary below - same results
        // message === "on" ? this.isEdtDisplayed = true : this.isEdtDisplayed = 'hello';
        console.log(`new edt display: ${this.isEdtDisplayed}`);
      }
    }
```

When I publish to the monitored topic `display_school_edt` (twice: one the message is `on` and the other time `off`), here is what I get on the console:

[image]

In other words, no matter if `on` or `off` is received, the condition is always false.

There is something obviously wrong with my code but the more I look, the better it looks.

---

Footnote: the fact that it is that specific protocol does not matter (it is a kind of bus often used with IoTs), you can assume that somehow `mqttMessage()` is executed with the parameters `topic` and `message` that are both strings.

Comment: About the footnote: can you debug and make *absolutely* sure that `message` is a string? Like `console.log(typeof message)`. I think that is the issue, and you should do `if (message+'' === 'on')` -- converting `message` to a string.

Comment: @trincot: ahhh, you are right. It is something strange actually (and therefore not aligned with the MQTT protocol BTW): `object`. When I `console.log(message)` I see `Uint8Array(3) [111, 102, 102]`. I am reading about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array. EDIT; .toString() is the solution. Would you mind just bootstraping an answer so that I can edit it with references and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed unexpected if `message` is of type string. However, it probably is not, and the only times you output `message`, you actually coerce it to string. So if you see from a previous output that it coerces to "no", then in the `if` condition you should do the same, and force that conversion to string:

```
if (message+'' === 'no')
```

NB: This will call `message.toString()`, just like it does when you reference it within a template literal as `${message}`.

Comment: I'd recommend writing `String(message)` or `message.toString()` instead of coercing by concatenation.

Comment: @Bergi: I actually used `.toString()` for clarity when I am back to this code in a month and start to wonder what I meant.